# Avoid initializing a variable to store each()'s returns

Tags: php, laravel, each

I have this code:

```
class Menu
{
    public function render()
    {
        $res = '';

        collect($this->items)->each(function ($item) use (&$res) {
            $res .= $item->render();
        });

        return $res;
    }
}
```

I would like to return the same value but removing `$res`. Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can employ [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
class Menu
{
    public function render()
    {
        return array_reduce(collect($this->items)->toArray(), function ($res, $item) {
            return $res . $item->render();
        }, '');
    }
}
```

but it is less efficient, since the value of `$res` will be copied instead being passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way:

```
class Menu
{
    public function render()
    {
        return collect($this->items())->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
            return $carry . $item->render();
        }, '');
    }
}
```